# On-premises replacement for Azure Blob Storage or Amazon S3 (flat file storage)?

Tags: azure, amazon-s3, storage, durability

What's a suitable durable storage replacement for Azure Blob Storage (and Amazon S3) for on-premise installations that are disconnected from the public internet? The development environment is C# - if it matters.

Losing live geo-replication is fine (offline geo-replicated backups work) but would like to retain the high-availability feature exhibited by Azure Blob Storage - meaning if one file server goes down, another one can continue service at the same (or predictable) location/URI till the 1st is restored.

Comment: Did you found something? I found Dell ECS https://www.dell.com/en-ae/dt/storage/ecs/index.htm#tab0=0&tab1=0

Answer (score 5):

In the meantime [minio](http://minio.io) could be a good solution as it provides S3 API compatible object storage.

Answer (score 4):

For object storage (the equivalent of S3 or Blob, accessed via API), there are several on-prem options from the likes of Cloudian (HyperStore), Dell (Elastic Cloud Storage), NetApp (StorageGrid Webscale), etc. There are also open source options like Swift back-ended by SwiftStack, Ceph, etc.

If you only need basic flat file storage in a highly-available (HA) manner and can do without API access, most NAS solutions offer this. You could also configure [Samba for HA](https://www.centos.org/docs/2/rh-cm-en-1.0/s1-service-samba.html).

Answer (score 0):

Like with Table Storage (your other question), there's no direct equivalent of these technologies but I would recommend looking into hybrid cloud storage system like [`StorSimple`](http://www.storsimple.com/storsimple-solution-features/).

Answer (score 0):

For Table Storage you can consider Etcd. You will have to put your Table Name, Partition Key and Row Key into the Key field, and serialize your object to the Value field, but it should be super fast and you can query by prefix, so PK querying will work, and also you can query by range, so time series querying by RK will also work.

PS. It's a filesystem-based database so you should be good for blobs too.